# Finding DB information from RMAN catalog database Recovery Catalog views

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, rman

I need to find the following 4 pieces of information about a target DB (version 11.2.0.4) from the RMAN database RC views:

1. Number of DB datafiles
2. Number of DB tempfiles
3. Oracle Version of the registered DB
4. The host that the registered DB resides on

So far I have the following:

Find the number of Datafiles

```
select max(file#) from rc_backup_set s, rc_backup_datafile d
where d.db_name='${DBNAME}'
and s.set_stamp=d.set_stamp and s.set_count=d.set_count
and s.completion_time > sysdate-1 /
```

Find the number of Tempfiles

```
select distinct(file#) from RC_TEMPFILE t where t.db_name='${DBNAME}' /
```

These give the correct answers in my limited tests but I'm not 100% sure they're correct. Does anybody know how to find these 4 pieces of info from the RC views?

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm grabbing my RC view info here: https://docs.oracle.com/html/E10643_07/rcviews001.htm

Comment: If anyone can confirm if the 2 posted SQL statements give accurate info that would also be a big help.

Comment: The 2 commands provided are correct. The other 2 pieces of info need to be found elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 SQL commands provided (to determine the number of datafiles and tempfiles) are correct. The other 2 pieces of info need to be found elsewhere - it's not possible to grab those details from the catalog.